# PyTables: Change Table expectedrows parameter dynamically

Tags: python, hdf5, pytables

Within PyTables [optimization tips](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html#informing-pytables-about-expected-number-of-rows-in-tables-or-arrays), we can find suggestion to append *expectedrows* parameter while creating new table - [File.create_table()](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html#tables.File.create_earray).

However, I couldn't find any information about the possibility of changing this parameter later. This would be reasonable as my table is not static and will grow over time and I want to use it on an ongoing basis.

Alternatively, is it possible, to create a new table (with new settings) and use data from other, already existing tables?

Alternatively, what is the best solution to handle this issue?

Comment: The value of `expectedrows` is different than the number of rows in your table (or earray). It is intended to estimate the maximum size expected and is used to set the chunkshape (that's why it's not saved as a parameter). Note default is `EXPECTED_ROWS_TABLE = 10000`. I modified my example (below) to use smaller/bigger values of `expectedrows` and printed the resulting `chunkshape`. That is the important parameter -- it controls the shape of the data chunk read/written in one I/O operation. Also, I added some code to demonstrate you can append data without changing `expectedrows`.

Comment: Thank you for the clear code below. It helps a lot. 
Now, when I'm aware I can practically change expectedrows, do you know what is the best practice? Should I make a table with some expectedrows value, and when this table grow enough, should I make another one with new expectedrows? Or is it better to set expectedrow from beginning large enough, to not change it too quickly? And don't care about my table is far less than settled parameter?

Comment: Answer depends on your I/O operations. I use default values. When you input `expectedrows`, PyTables calculates an appropriate value of `chunkshape` for the Table. It is the shape used for each read or write "chunk". The relationship is not linear. I modified my answer to tabulate `chunkshape` vs `expectedrows`. Also, it doesn't have to be exact -- look at the optimization graphs (w/ a 15GB file). It's OK if you set  `expectedrows=1_000_000`, and the table grows to `1_500_000`. I would create a new table. if it grows to `100_000_000` rows AND you do a lot of I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to access the value of `expectedrows` or change after creating a table. However, it's "relatively easy" to read a table and copy the data to a new table (either in the same file or another file). Note: if you create a new table and delete the old one, you will want to run `ptrepack` as described in the  [PyTables optimization tips](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/optimization.html#informing-pytables-about-expected-number-of-rows-in-tables-or-arrays) you mentioned above.)

Simple example below:

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

with tb.File('SO_71267946.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    arr_dt = [('i', int), ('x',float), ('y',float)]
    arr = np.empty(dtype=arr_dt, shape=10,)
    arr['i'] = [i for i in range(10)]
    arr['x'] = [2.*x for x in range(10)]
    arr['y'] = [4.*y for y in range(10)]
    ex_tbl = h5f.create_table('/','Example',obj=arr, expectedrows=1_000)
    print(ex_tbl.chunkshape) 

# create more data to add more rows to the table
    arr = np.empty(dtype=arr_dt, shape=20,)
    arr['i'] = [i for i in range(10,30)]
    arr['x'] = [2.*x for x in range(10,30)]
    arr['y'] = [4.*y for y in range(10,30)]
    ex_tbl.append(arr)

# Copy to a new table in the same file:
    xfer = h5f.root.Example.read()
    ex_tbl2 = h5f.create_table('/','Example2',obj=xfer, expectedrows=1_000_000)
    print(ex_tbl2.chunkshape) 

# Copy to a new table in the new file:
with tb.File('SO_71267946.h5', 'r') as h5r, \
     tb.File('SO_71267946_2.h5', 'w') as h5w:

     xfer = h5r.root.Example.read()
     ex_tbl2 = h5w.create_table('/','Example2',obj=xfer, expectedrows=1_000_000)
```

Table below shows `chuckshape` calculated for different values of `expectedrows`. (`chuckshape` is number of rows read from a Table in a single I/O operation.)

| expectedrows | chunkshape |
| --- | --- |
| 10_000 | (3276,) |
| 100_000 | (3276,) |
| 1_000_000 | (6553,) |
| 10_000_000 | (13107,) |
| 1_000_000_000 | (52428,) |